# Switching between http and https in yii

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, yii

Hi i wanted some of the pages of my yii app to be https and some to be http. i tried many things and failed before ending up with this Excellent wiki by Mr. Qiang.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/407/url-management-for-websites-with-secure-and-nonsecure-pages/
which works great by the way. it properly redirects all the specified actions to https and others to http. 
But there is one problem. if i type my domain name say https://example.com (without specifying action name like https://example.com/site/index) it redirects to non secure url http://example.com. if i specify the action name it will work alright. but when i use just the domain name it goes to non secure page. i tryed to redirect using htaccess but it is not working.. can anyone help please

Comment: Why, just have the whole site secured - what benefit do you get to having some unsecured pages?

Comment: i cant do that because in some pages i am using some non secure content fetching (iframes and all). so if we use SSL in those pages the browser will give warnings for users

Comment: What is your default action? site/index? Quick look at router code says that if route is not in secureRoutes array, it get's prefixed with non-secure http